# MongoDB Node Driver Typescript Definition - GridFSBucket Support

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

I'm trying to use GridFSBucket and related classes in my node typescript project but the typescript definition I have gotten from DefinitelyTyped doesn't seem to support it.

How can I do one (or more) of the following:

1. Find an updated version? Does someone have one?
2. Tell typescript to ignore just these particular items?
3. Use a merge declaration where I can add GridFSBucket and related as
   a top level declaration so typescript will stop complaining? I tried
   doing this and kept getting an error that I cannot add to top level
   declarations.

Answer (score 0):

When I was trying to do a merge declaration before I was doing it inside the file I was having the typescript error in (trying to be lazy). Moving the declare stuff into its own file (**my_custom\mongodb.d.ts**) I am able to add the stuff I need. To be clear I am still compiling against the official mongodb d.ts as well.

```
...

export class GridFSBucket {
    constructor(db, options:IGridFSBuckerOptions);

    openDownloadStream:(id,options?:IOpenDownloadStreamOptions)=>GridFSBucketReadStream;
}

...
```